# Don't know how to use varchar variable in select clause of query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, varchar

I''m trying to use a varchar variable in my select, but its registering as a string and outputting just the string itself instead of treating it like an actual column.

Not very many solutions online, as it seems like this isn't a problem very many run into.

```
Declare @counter INT = 0
Declare @totalcol INT
Declare @col VARCHAR(50)


select @totalcol = count(*)
FROM [Loyalty_DW].information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Transactions'


while (@counter < @totalcol)
    begin
        select @col = COLUMN_NAME   
        from [Loyalty_DW].information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'Transactions'
        order by (select null)
        offset @counter rows
        fetch next 1 rows only

        select distinct(@col)
        from [Loyalty_DW].dbo.Transactions

        set @counter += 1
    end
```

The output is just a string with no actual data returned. The same as if I were to say select 'asdf' from tablename where ... it would just output 'asdf'.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CURSOR` statement rather than `WHILE` statement, as Gordon says you need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE  @columName AS NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE  @sqlText AS NVARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM [Loyalty_DW].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Transactions'
ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)

OPEN cursor_name  
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @columName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 

    SET @sqlText = N'SELECT DISTINCT ' +  @columName + ' FROM [Loyalty_DW].dbo.Transactions'
    EXEC (@sqlText)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @columName 
END

CLOSE cursor_name
DEALLOCATE cursor_name
```